# Showing quotient rings are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can anyone explain to me how to show two quotient rings are isomorphic? For my particular case. Both quotient rings are based off ideals in the ring $\mathbb Z_3[X]$:
$$
\mathbb Z_3[X]\big/(X^3-X+1)\mathbb Z_3[X] \cong 
\mathbb Z_3[X]\big/(X^3-X^2+1)\mathbb Z_3[X]
$$

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two arguments you can use, special to this particular case. Before I say anything about these, let me say that it’s not clear to me whether, in the *general* situation, where you have a groundfield $k$ and two irreducible polynomials $f$ and $g$ of the same degree, you an easily determine an isomorphism between $k[x]/(f)$ and $k[x]/(g)$. Indeed, there may be various *ad hoc* methods of deciding that the two are not isomorphic, but I, being only partially educated here, am unaware of any general such.

Back to your two examples. The polynomials are $f(X)=X^3-X+1$ and $g=X^3-X^2+1$. Ah, but $g(X)=X^3f(1/X)$, telling you immediately how to get an isomorphism. If $\alpha$ is a root of the one and $\beta$ is a root of the other, your isomorphism can send $\alpha\mapsto1/\beta$.

More generally but less explicitly, both are cubic irreducibles over $\mathbb F_3$, so that in both cases the quotient is a field of cardinality $3^3=27$; but the general theory says that there is, up to isomorphism, only one field of each possible finite cardinality $q=p^m$. So the two fields have to be isomorphic. The theory does not construct an isomorphism for you, however, far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

1. $X^3-X+1$ and $X^3-X^2+1$ are irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb Z_3[X]$.
2. $\mathbb Z_3[X]\big/(X^3-X+1)\mathbb Z_3[X]$ and $\mathbb Z_3[X]\big/(X^3-X^2+1)\mathbb Z_3[X]$ are both finite fields with $27$ elements.
3. Finite fields having the same number of elements are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we wished to show that a quotient ring $A/\mathfrak a$ is isomorphic to another ring $B$. A very useful technique is to define a surjective ring homomorphism $\phi:A\to B$ such that $\ker \phi=\mathfrak a$. That $A/\mathfrak a\simeq B$ then follows from the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with all the variables. Any way you can do an example with the ideals i gave or a similar setup?

Comment: @user26857 The problem statement you are reading is vastly different than its original form. The original problem statement was something to the effect of "how can I show that two quotient rings are isomorphic". There were no specific rings mentioned and thus I think this answer is very useful as a guiding principle. Downvotes welcome though.